# Add two list in one tuple

Tags: list, tuples

I have two list, let say `a=[0,1,2,3]` and `b=[4,5,6]`, in each step I remove one elements from `a` and add it to the `b` until list `a` be empty. In each step I want to have both list in one tuple like this :

first step : `({4, 5, 6, 0}, {1, 2, 3})`

next : `({4, 5, 6, 0, 1}, {2, 3})`
...
finally: `({4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3}, {})`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `a.pop(0)` to remove and get the value of the first item of `a`, and then use `b.append()` to add this to `b`. `while a:` part is executed until `a` is empty.

```py
a = [0, 1, 2, 3]; b = [4, 5, 6]

while a:
    b.append(a.pop(0))
    tup = (b, a)
    print(tup)
```

Output:

```
([4, 5, 6, 0], [1, 2, 3])
([4, 5, 6, 0, 1], [2, 3])
([4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2], [3])
([4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3], [])
```